# Retrofit 2 appending post to requestbody in intercept

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I have this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        HttpUrl url = request.httpUrl().newBuilder()
                     .addQueryParameter("platform", "android")
                     .addQueryParameter("app_version", com.package.BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
                     .build();
        Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
});
```

but would also like to append an additional post key-value to the request body containing the userkey. This would look something like

```
    RequestBody newBody = RequestBody.create(request.body().contentType(),request.body().content+ request.addPost("sUserKey","3254345kdskf");
...
...
 Request newRequest = chain.request()
.newBuilder()
.url(url)
.post(newBody)
.build();
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: During an okhttp intercept, how would you add an additional POST?

Comment: you want to do a post request to a different endpoint ?

Comment: Not quite. I want the endpoint to remain the same, but to add additional parameters.  I would like to add ("sUserkey","345i34oj53i4s")

Comment: do you want to add something to the body ?

Comment: Yes. I want to add the post to the requestbody, without replacing the current body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94464/discussion-between-nic-capdevila-and-blackbelt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without creating additional class.

```
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        String parameter = "&" + name + "=" + value;
        Request newRequest = interceptRequest(request, parameter)
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
});
```

This is simple method that create new request.

```
 public static Request interceptRequest(@NotNull Request request, @NotNull String parameter)
            throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Sink sink = Okio.sink(baos);
        BufferedSink bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(sink);

        /**
         * Write old params
         * */
        request.body().writeTo(bufferedSink);

        /**
         * write to buffer additional params
         * */
        bufferedSink.writeString(parameter, Charset.defaultCharset());

        RequestBody newRequestBody = RequestBody.create(
                request.body().contentType(),
                bufferedSink.buffer().readUtf8()
        );

        return request.newBuilder().post(newRequestBody).build();
    }
```

Also you can get it from [Gist](https://gist.github.com/silvestrpredko/5e7f07fa4ef48bf414d6)

Answer (score 7):

Appending to the `RequestBody` is not straight forward.  Here is a sketch of a custom `RequestBody` that will add a post parameter.  Couple of caveats -- you will want to add some error checking, like making sure the existing body is not null. The given code also assumes all calls coming to this interceptor are POSTs.  If that is not that case, you'll need to check the incoming request type before applying the new body.  Also, since this just copies the new parameter into the body, you'll need to make sure the name and body are already url encoded if needed.

```
class AddPostParamRequestBody extends RequestBody {

    final RequestBody body;
    final String parameter;

    AddPostParamRequestBody(RequestBody body, String name, String value) {
        this.body = body;
        this.parameter = "&" + name + "=" + value;
    }

    @Override
    public long contentLength() throws IOException {
        return body.contentLength() + parameter.length();
    }

    @Override
    public MediaType contentType() {
        return body.contentType();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink bufferedSink) throws IOException {
        body.writeTo(bufferedSink);
        bufferedSink.writeString(parameter, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

}
```

Then you can use in your interceptor --

```
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        HttpUrl url = request.httpUrl().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("added", "param").build();
        AddPostParamRequestBody newBody = new AddPostParamRequestBody(request.body(), "sUserKey","3254345kdskf");
        Request newRequest = request.newBuilder().post(newBody).url(url).build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
});
```

Your other option is to the include an extra `Field` annotation in your retrofit definition and pass it in on every call, but I assume you were trying to avoid that.

Comment: what is added and param means in addQueryParameter("added", "param") query.?