# Retrofit 2 append @Body request

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to intercept all my retrofit calls using  HTTP request body with the @Body annotation, and append them with a new generated String.

So far I managed to intercept the body and generate the string but can't added it to the request.

I used this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574691/retrofit-2-appending-post-to-requestbody-in-intercept) but the writeTo() method seems to add my param as @Field and not in the actual request body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i add "token":"value" in old requestbody

```
public static Request interceptRequest(Request request)
        throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Sink sink = Okio.sink(baos);
    BufferedSink bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(sink);

    /**
     * Write old params
     * */
    request.body().writeTo(bufferedSink);

    if (UserModelManager.getInstance().isLogin()) {
        String hasd = bufferedSink.buffer().readString(Charset.defaultCharset());//result like this [text={}]
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{.*\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(hasd);

        if(matcher.find()){
            String oldBody = matcher.group();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(oldBody);
                jsonObject.put("token", UserModelManager.getInstance().getUser().token);
                bufferedSink.flush();

                bufferedSink.writeString(jsonObject.toString(), Charset.defaultCharset());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    /**
     * write to buffer additional params
     * */




    RequestBody newRequestBody = RequestBody.create(
            request.body().contentType(),
            bufferedSink.buffer().readUtf8()
    );
    return request.newBuilder().post(newRequestBody).build();
}
```